# How to automate the pass phrases when GPG signing dpkg-buildpackage?

Tags: dpkg, packaging

I'm using dpkg-buildpackage and I would like to fully automate my scripts, but I cannot find how to GPG sign the packages and automate entering the pass phrases in my Continuous Integration System. I don't want to use the '-us -uc' parameters, because I do want to sign them.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe a solution using `debsign`, see [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/665341/396913)

Answer (score 1):

If your keyring is already unlocked, all you have to do is:

> setup gpg-agent
>
> So you won't be prompted for your passphrase a whole bunch of times...
>
> `sudo aptitude install gnupg-agent pinentry-gtk2 pinentry-curses`
>   replace 0xD34DB33F with your GPG Key ID
>   `export GPGKEY=0xD34DB33F`
>   `killall -q gpg-agent`
>   `eval $(gpg-agent --daemon)`

and

> `export DEBEMAIL="address@example.com"`
>   `export DEBFULLNAME="Your full name as it appears on the GPG key"`

from [here](http://docs.bcfg2.org/installation/building-packages.html#building-debian-packages)

I can attest to the second part.  The first part is a copy-paste, but it seems legitimate.  I would think you would still have to unlock the key once, but it would stay unlocked.

Comment: How to make it persistent? The agent asks on every build.

Answer (score 1):

Comment out:

```
use-agent
```

in `~/.gnupg/gpg.conf` . And

```
dpkg-buildpackage -p'gpg --no-tty --passphrase <passphrase>'
```

or

```
dpkg-buildpackage -p'gpg --no-tty --passphrase-file <passphrase file>'
```

---

Edit:

**WARNING**: *serious security Risk!* 
Everyone able to access such a script can distribute malicious software in your name

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, since it precisely resolves the given problem.

Comment: However: placing your private key's password into any kind of file is risky and weakens the chain of trust for package distribution. When attackers get access to this script or even just your command history, they can inject malicious code and get it distributed to many users without further interaction, since users trust your signature

Answer (score 0):

gpg-agent method does not avoid asking passphrase to be entered with keyboard.
I've seen Freight uses

```
gpg --batch --passphrase-fd ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very experienced in this but I would suggest:

1. Create new user account
2. Create an unlocked key for it
3. Use that user only for building packages or may be just signing using `debsign` to keep that account safe from build process and scripts.

That if you really trust safety of the machine. Anyway, you were already going to store an unsafe password in a command for unlocking.

Comment: A variation of this scheme is basically what the Ubuntu-PPA-Builder does: you sign the _source package_ regularly with your key, and setup the automated builder for binary packages such as to trust only your signing key and then sign the packages with another dedicated key, which is then published for your users. However, **still very dangerous** must keep your build machine very safe

Answer (score 0):

##### Seed password once into gpg-agent

In addition to the other methods already mentioned here, it is possible to *seed your gpg-agent* with a passphrase; you may build that into a startup script, and require manual intervention once, when your build machine starts up. Such a setup is slightly more secure, since the passphrase only resides in memory. However, an attacker able to read memory contents could still steal your passphrase and then **distribute malicious software in your name**

1. fist stop an existing agent

   ```
   gpgconf --kill gpg-agent
   ```
2. then start a new instance and allow to inject the passphrase; moreover, we can increase the time-to-live here

   ```
   gpg-agent --default-cache-ttl 3600 --max-cache-ttl 86400 --allow-preset-passphrase --daemon
   ```
3. inject the passphrase of your *signing subkey* — You will be prompted to enter the passphrase when this command runs.

   ```
   /usr/lib/gnupg/gpg-preset-passphrase --preset <keygrip>
   ```

For this to work, you need the "keygrip" of your *signing subkey* (not the master key!). Use `gpg` to find out that information

```
gpg --with-keygrip --list-secret-key <YourUserID>
```

The *signing subkey* is listed below the master key and the Email addresses, it is typically marked as `ssb` and `[S]` or `[SA]`

---

**Hints**

- sometimes you need to `export GPG_TTY=$(tty)` for the `pinentry` to work
- you may start a sub-shell from the gpg-agent

  ```
  gpg-agent [..further.options..] --daemon /bin/bash
  ```

  this way, the agent exits when the sub-shell exits and any password you set in the sub-shell is gone afterwards.