# Automatically sign package files from debuild and upload with dput

Tags: ppa, packaging, launchpad, gnupg

I've created a source package for I library I'm working on. I use `debuild` to build it and then I can successfully upload it with `dput`.

Now I want to set it up so that I can do this automatically from Jenkins. The main issue I'm running into is signing the .dsc and .changes files. What I'm trying to do is sign the packages with `gpg` rather than having `debuild` do it. This way I can sign the files automatically with the gpg option `--passphrase-fd 0`.

So I use `debuild` with the options `-uc` and `-us` and then clearsign the files with `gpg`.  But when I do this it creates a separate `.dsc.asc` and `source.changes.asc`. When I then try to upload with `dput` I get the error

```
Checking signature on .changes
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: the signature could not be verified.
Please remember that the signature file (.sig or .asc)
should be the first file given on the command line.
```

This would seem to suggest that I should list the `.asc` file as an argument to `dput` but I can't get this to work.

Comment: What's the question?I'd suggest using a gpg key without a passphrase, for automated signing. Or just use launchpad's Daily Builds feature.

Comment: The question is: If I sign the files with gpg instead of letting debuild do it, I get a separate source.changes.asc file instead of it signing the sources.changes file in place. How do I upload with dput in this case.

Comment: Also, I don't want to use a gpg key without a passphrase and the project scm is git, so I can't use the daily build feature because it is (as far as I can tell) only applicable to bzr.

Comment: You can set up an automatic import from the git repository to launchpad

Comment: Why do you want to use a passphrase, when you are going to be storing this passphrase in a script, that seems stupid. Create a key without a passphrase, that's only used by this job.

Comment: We normally sign with `debsign` but if you want to drive gpg by hand, use `-clearsign`, and then move the `.asc` onto the `.changes` / `.dsc`

Comment: Ahh. I can create a key specifically for this and upload that key to Launchpad. Then use that key only for this. You're right that was a little stupid. I don't know why that was so hard to figure out.

Comment: Maybe you should put that down as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy answer is: Launchpad daily builds, they do all of this for you, fairly securely.

If you want to be doing source upload from Jenkins, then I suggest creating a key just for this Jenkins job. Having a passphrase on it wouldn't improve the security very much, if the Jenkins job would have to know the passphrase, so one might as well just leave it unprotected.

If you really want to sign the `.dsc` and `.changes` files by hand, sign them with `gpg --clearsign`, and rename the `.asc` files over the originals.

Answer (score 8):

I found the following solution with `debsign` and the `-p` option:

- use `debuild` without the signature, as you mentioned
- use then `debsign` with `-p` option setting the passphrase to use, like this

  ```
  debsign \
    -p'gpg --passphrase-file /home/myname/my_passphrase_file.txt --batch --no-use-agent'\
    -S -kMYKEYID package_source.change
  ```

Still having some other issues, but this part looks like working. Signing files with GPG directly does not work as the checksums computed during the `debuild` are changed.

I always prefer storing keys with passphrase anyway.

Comment: This should be the correct answer

Comment: **Warning**: anyone with access to the `my_passphrase` file can publish packages in your name and maybe inject malicious code, which is then installed automatically for all users trusting your signature!!!

Comment: This is why you use gpg subkeys: that specific subkey can be revoked without compromising too much your gpg identity. **Any** fully automated method needs a passphrase to be stored clear text: there is no magic here. The computer on which this is executed should be secured as you transfer trust to that computer to sign on your behalf.